# SELECT DISTINCT from one column based on MAX of another

Tags: mysql

I have a query that returns the relative activity of users in each region. I want to be returned that list but with each user only in 1 region, so I want to filter out on everyone's MAX applications.

The current query:

```
SELECT 
    r.region_id,
    ha.user_id,
    count(ha.user_id) AS applications 
FROM 
    sit_applications ha
LEFT JOIN 
    listings_regions r 
        ON 
            r.listingID = ha.listingID
            AND deleted = 0
WHERE 
    ha.datetime_applied >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
GROUP BY 
    ha.user_id, r.region_id
HAVING 
    applications > 0
ORDER BY 
    r.region_id DESC
```

I need to filter this query so I only grab each user_id once, and with it's biggest applications for a region. This is so I have a list of all the top performers for each region, with no duplicate users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, you have three basic ways to do this:

- Using variables
- Using a complex `join`
- Using a hack with `substring_index()` and `group_concat()`.

The complex `join` is really a mess when you have aggregation queries.  The hack is fun, but does have its limitation.  So, let's consider the variables method:

```
SELECT ur.*
FROM (SELECT ur.*,
             (@rn := if(@u = user_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@u := user_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      FROM (SELECT r.region_id, ha.user_id, count(ha.user_id) AS applications 
            FROM sit_applications ha LEFT JOIN 
                 listings_regions r 
                 ON r.listingID = ha.listingID AND deleted = 0
            WHERE ha.datetime_applied >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
            GROUP BY ha.user_id, r.region_id
            HAVING applications > 0
           ) ur CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @u := -1, @rn := 0) params
      ORDER BY user_id, applications DESC
     ) ur
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Note:  Aspects of your query do not really make sense, even though I left them in.  You are using `LEFT JOIN`, so `r.region_id` could be `NULL` -- and that is usually not desirable.  You have a `HAVING` clause that is totally unnecessary, because the `COUNT()` is always 1 -- assuming that `ha.user_id` is never `NULL`.  I suspect that the logic could be replaced with an `INNER JOIN`, no `HAVING` clause, and `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: It's evolved from another query in the code, that is why it has vestigial conditions.

Comment: r.region_id won't be null, a row in the table is created the same time a row in sit_applications is.

Comment: @BeaverusIV . . . I'm curious why this answer would be downvoted.

Comment: I am not the one downvoting, am curious too.

Comment: I get 'unknown seqnum in where clause'.

Comment: @BeaverusIV . . . That should be (and now is) `rn`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping the query and extracting out what you want:

```
SELECT t2.user_id, t2.region_id, t2.applications
FROM
(
    SELECT t.user_id, MAX(t.applications) AS applications
    FROM
    (
        SELECT r.region_id, ha.user_id, COUNT(ha.user_id) AS applications 
        FROM sit_applications ha LEFT JOIN listings_regions r 
            ON r.listingID = ha.listingID AND deleted = 0
        WHERE ha.datetime_applied >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
        GROUP BY ha.user_id, r.region_id
        HAVING applications > 0
    ) t
    GROUP BY t.user_id
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT r.region_id, ha.user_id, COUNT(ha.user_id) AS applications 
    FROM sit_applications ha LEFT JOIN listings_regions r 
        ON r.listingID = ha.listingID AND deleted = 0
    WHERE ha.datetime_applied >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
    GROUP BY ha.user_id, r.region_id
    HAVING applications > 0
) t2
    ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.applications = t2.applications
```

Comment: I was on a cell phone when I answered this.  Let's see what the OP has to say.

Comment: If I SELECT region_id out too is it going to get the right one?

Comment: No.  You will need to join back to your original table if you want the `region_id`.

Comment: How would that work? Could you add to the code example, I'll update question to make it more clear I need the region id.

Comment: Is there a more concise way to do this? I feel like I'm approaching this wrong if the answer looks like that.

Comment: If you were using SQL Server or Oracle, you could use something called Common Table Expressions (CTE), which would make the query much easier to read.  But alas, you are using MySQL.

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted?  Although not my favorite approach, it is certainly a reasonable answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Strawberry downvoted me when I had an earlier version of the query which only returned `user_id`  and the aggregate.  Even that was reasonable, but the OP did not initially make it clear what was wanted.